# Kodi font configure - ASUS NAS

Tags: fonts, nas, language, kodi

I have worked my way into a corner, trying to configure Kodi.

**Background:** Brand new NAS, AS6104T. Installed Kodi, to allow spouse to watch her TV dramas on Youtube. The shows are from Thailand, so a Thai font is essential.

Connection to Youtube was made, but - all Thai characters were replaced by meaningless rectangles. So, I went to the configuration menu, and selected THAI as the main language. The system said "changing to Thai"... and when it finished, EVERYTHING was meaningless rectangles.

**Problem:**

1. I can't guess which set of rectangles to select, to change the font back to English.
2. Logically, Kodi keeps this in a file setting - but the ASUS NAS keeps Kodi as an "app" which is not visible to the user. Saves them from people rummaging through the files, but leaves me in a pile of trouble.

Does anyone know the steps I can BLINDLY follow, to go through the unreadable menu system and reconfigure the language?

Does anyone know how to access the Kodi "App" files on an ASUS NAS?

Or - do I need to remove Kodi and re-install?

Comment: If you want a step-by-step of what I did wrong, read: https://www.tvaddons.ag/kodi-language/
Setting "Thai" for the international language was my undoing.

Answer (score 0):

Working from the main menu:

1. Selecting the last menu item to the right. When the text is readable, this is the "Systems" menu.
2. In the sub-menu that appears, select the first itemon the LEFT ("settings"). Hopefully, you now see another menu, along with a picture of a couple of gears.
3. The top item in this menu is the nect selection ("Appearance")
4. Almost there - in this last menu, the top item is "skin" and the SECOND item is "International".
5. At the top of the drop-down list that appears to the right, is the LANGUAGE setting. Click on this, and select a language from the drop-down list.

This got me a readable, functional setup. The original fault persists: Text in Thai gets converted to squares / rectangles.